# args.length does not give correct index

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
        if (args.length == 0)
            System.out.println("No args");
        else
            System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");
    }
}
```

It shows output "*no args*" first and if I comment the 3rd,4th,5th line of code it shows "*one args*". 
Could not understand how these outputs are coming .

Comment: depends whether you pass any input from the command line.

Comment: If I pass one input from command line it shows two args why ?

Comment: The argument length is zero. So `if` evaluates to `true` and it prints `No args`. If you remove the `if/else` condition then you merely print out the first array element, which is `one` concatenated with `args`

Comment: It's not really clear which part you don't understand. If `args.length` is `0`, and `numbers[0]` is `"one"`, `numbers[args.length]` will be `"one"`. You might want to insert a few more `System.out.println` statements if you're having trouble figuring out what the code is doing.

Comment: Poor title. Edit to summarize specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

With **no** arguments given this would print `No args`

```
String[] numbers = {"one","two","three","four"};
if(args.length==0)                       //l3
    System.out.println("No args");       //l4
else                                     //l5
    System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");
```

---

*Comment line 3 to line 5 :* 
With **no** arguments given this would print `one args` because array index starts at 0 so `numbers[args.length] = numbers[0] = 'one'`

```
String[] numbers = {"one","two","three","four"};
System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");
```

You should change to :

- `System.out.println(numbers[args.length-1] + " args");`

*OR*

- `String[] numbers = {"no(zero)","one","two","three","four"};` and remove `if/else`

Answer (score 2):

The output will be `No args` regardless of whether the `numbers` array contains one or more elements because you're checking if the `args` array is of length `0` then do something else do something. you're not checking against the `numbers` array.

the statement `System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");` will only execute when `args` has a length greater than `0` and this can be achieved by passing input from the command line.

I can't remember exactly what it's called but there is a tool in most IDEs where you can pass input to the `main` method rather than using an actual command line.

Lastly, but not least you're probably looking to do `numbers[args.length-1]` rather than `numbers[args.length]` as arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass any command line argument, length of `args[]` is equal to 0. Length of `args[]` is the number of arguments passed in the command line (separated by spaces). According to these information:

```
if (args.length == 0)   // Yes, args.length is equal to 0, so...
    System.out.println("No args");   // This line is printed and "else" part is not being executed.
else
    System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");   // Not executed
```

But, if you comment out the following lines:

```
String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
// if (args.length == 0)
//     System.out.println("No args");
// else
       System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");
```

Only this line is being executed: `System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");`, so you print to the console: value of `numbers[0]` which is "`one`" and you append " `args`" to it. The result is: "`one args`".

By the way, if you want to print correct number of arguments in `else` part of an `if-else` statement, you should change the following line, from:

```
System.out.println(numbers[args.length] + " args");
```

to:

```
System.out.println(numbers[args.length - 1] + " args");
```

as indexes of arrays start from 0, not from 1. Check that your code rather doesn't print what you expect it to by adding these simple lines:

```
System.out.println("numbers[0] = " + numbers[0]); // Output at index 0: one
System.out.println("numbers[1] = " + numbers[1]); // Output at index 1: two
System.out.println("numbers[2] = " + numbers[2]); // Output at index 2: three
```